# How to investigate OOM of too many objects in Eclipse Memory Analyzer?

Tags: java, hive, out-of-memory, eclipse-memory-analyzer

In an application(actually it is HiveServer2), I've encountered OOM error and got a heap dump.

Through Eclipse Memory Analyzer(EMA), I've found that many `LinkedHashMap$Entry` consumed almost all of the heap memory (16GB), but I want to know which components use such a lot of objects.

What prevents me from investigating is that the heap dump is around 16GB itself, so some of the operations of EMA don't work in my laptop. Anyway, does anybody know how I can get to know that in Eclipse Memory Analyzer?

[image]

Comment: Look in your code for static Maps that are loaded but never unloaded.

Comment: Thx for the comment! Actually this is Apache Hadoop's Hive application. I just want to know where to investigate the source code of Hive.

Comment: I doubt that you'll get far with that.  It's something that you're doing.